# length of a polar curve

Tags: calculus

I'm asked to find the exact length of the curve $$r=\theta$$ from $$0\leq \theta \leq \pi /2$$. But I down to $$\sqrt{\theta ^2 +1}\,d\theta$$ and am not sure how to integrate that part. Any help?

Comment: You need to precede the `\sqrt` command by a backslash.

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29) is your friend.

Comment: Wolfram also doesn't show the derivation only the answer.

Comment: You'll need to use inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: This link may be useful: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarArcLength.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but a bit late for that. None the less it was all taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

With $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$ and thus $1+\sinh^2x=\cosh^2x$, you have

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+\theta^2}\,\mathrm d\theta
&=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\cosh^2 x}\,\mathrm d\left(\sinh x\right)
\\
&=
\int_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}\pi/2}\cosh^2x\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=
\left[\frac12\left(x+\sinh x\cosh x\right)\right]_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}\pi/2}
\\
&=
\frac12\left(\operatorname{arsinh}\frac\pi2+\frac\pi2\sqrt{1+\left(\frac\pi2\right)^2}\right)\;.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Hmm yeah I somehow knew it would end up being hyperbolic trig functions. Only thing is we haven't learned to work with those yet. Thank you though!

Comment: @John: Well, it's not just a question of whether to work with them -- the *answer* contains one, so there's no way of arriving at it without using them. You could use the [logarithmic representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function#Logarithmic_representation), though, if you want to avoid explicitly using them. But I don't see how to find that

$$
\frac12\left(x\sqrt{1+x^2}+\log\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)\right)
$$

is an antiderivative of $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ without using hyperbolic functions at some point.